# cascading ssh with expect

Tags: ubuntu, expect

I am new to `expect` command.

I am trying to ssh to `server1` via `server2`. The following script connect to `server2`.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh user2@server2
set prompt ":|#|\\\$"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send "password2\r"
interact
```

The question is how to proceed. How to connect to `server1` from `server2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, To `Expect`, you just have to send some commands and get a response. From the `Expect`'s perspective, you have to spawn a `ssh` session and then you can send whatever commands you want. That *whatever* command can also be a `ssh` command.

**Approach 1 :**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set server1 190.x.x.x
set user1 root
set pwd1 "mypwd1"
set server2 130.x.x.x
set user2 dinesh
set pwd2 "mypwd2"
spawn ssh $user2@$server2
expect "password:"
send "$pwd2\r";
expect "\\\$"
send "pwd\r"; # Just executing the 'pwd' command
expect "\\\$"
send "hostname\r" ; # Also executing 'hostname' command for your reference
expect "\\\$"
send "ssh $user1@$server1\r"
expect "password:"
send "$pwd1\r";
expect "# $"
send "pwd\r"
expect "# $"
send "hostname\r"
expect "# $"
```

**Approach 2 :**

Surprisingly, there is one more easy way is there. ssh itself will support cascading the command by use of adding `-t` flag in it.

```
 ssh -t user@outerhost ssh root@innerhost
```

Applying this logic in our code, we can have,

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set pwd1 "mypwd1"
set pwd2 "mypwd2"
spawn ssh -t user@outerhost  ssh user@innerhost
expect "password:"
send "$pwd2\r"
expect "password:"
send "$pwd1\r";
expect "# $"
send "pwd\r"; # Just executing 'pwd' command
expect "# $"
```

Reference for Approach 2 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15161956

**Note :** If your main intention is to execute commands only in the innerhost and the outerhost is just like a by-pass, then approach 2 is preferable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to do the Approach 2, the problem is it does connect to innerhost, but it don't keeps the session open. When I try I run some command from the terminal it closes. Is there are any way I could keep the connection open in the terminal?

Comment: @fog : Trying adding the `ConnectTimeout` while making the ssh connection. `ssh -o ConnectTimeout=3600` will give 1 hour of connection timeout value.